# How do I make Limited Dissolve 'stick'

Tags: edit-mode

I have a complex model (272883 faces) which I apply Limited Dissolve to and then faces reduces to 91796 (very nice). I export the model as a MSFS glTF but when I import the faces are 175076. I am wondering why the faces reduced to 91796 only to 'expand' again. I seem to have everything 'ticked' in the export MSFS giTF panel.
BEFORE LIMITED DISSOLVE
[image]
AFTER DISSOLVE
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hot sure what you mean. YES MSFS. Don't know how to display face count in MSFS. I have added a screen shot (above) of the imported glTF model which I exported after Limited Dissolve when displayed 91797 faces (second image) when exported but 176076 when imported (third image).

Comment: Notice in last image that tri count matches face count. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/234601/15543  gltf format   breaks faces down all faces  into triangles. _eg_ if you were to export and import the default cube, it would come back triangulated.  See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167383/15543

Comment: Another way to put it: if exporting to gltf look at  the triangle count

Comment: Thanks for the explanation batFINGER. So Limited Dissolve doesn't reduce triangles? Is there a method to do this other than using decimate? I am attempting to reduce the polygons for MSFS to a minimum without too much distortion as it affects 'frames per second'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender counts polygons as **one** face, but glTF cuts polygons into **multiple** triangular faces.
You can display the resulting triangles in *Scene Statistics.*

<sup>Example of using Limited Dissolve</sup>
[image]

Comment: Thanks Jachym. I have recently been using Statistics to show number of faces but didn't know that they are divided into triangles (should have gone to specsavers as they say).

Comment: No problem, I also didn't know glTF triangulates faces :)