# Why exported glTF file, all faces became from quads to triangle

Tags: gltf

Hi I'm a newbie to blender. I've exported my model from Blender to glTF. When I do export it, I see all faces are made of triangles in wireframe mode. Do you guys know why it converts quads to triangles?

[image]

Comment: Hi :). glTF format currently does not support quads, only triangles. To keep quads, export to OBJ instead

Comment: There's a reason why glTF does this.  See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167383/18161

Comment: Tris are the base of any rendering engine and graphics API. Quads are not supported everywhere. So it makes more sense to export in tris, for best support. So glTF format chose this scheme.